# Microsoft Edge - pending ajax call is executed with null parameters after page reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a situation in Edge where a pending ajax call (POST) is executed with null parameters after a page reload.

ajax/set_page is a php function that updates the column 'page' in the book table.

When I debug the code in Chrome, the database is updated as soon as I step over the $.ajax call. In Edge, the database is not updated until later in the program thread.

```
next_page {
  update_page {
    set_page {
    ------------ Chrome db -> page = 11, Edge db -> page = 11
       $.ajax({POST}); 
    -----------> Chrome -> call to server, db -> page = 12, 
                 Edge no server call, db -> page = 11
    };
  };
  if last_page
     do stuff
     if IE11 or Edge
       location.reload()
        ----------> Edge -> call to server with null parameters, db -> page = 11
};

not last page
  ----------> Edge -> call to server, db -> page = 12
  <---------- Chrome, Edge ajax success!
```

It looks like when the page is reloaded, the POST parameters are deleted but the ajax request is still executed.

Why is the ajax call with null parameters being sent to my server? Is there anything I can do to prevent it or do I just need to catch it on the server side?

Comment: did you try avoid the ajax call using a return alter the reload? can you kill the request before to reload the page?

Comment: I work on the Edge team and would be happy to take a closer look into this issue for you. Can you stand up a small demo that repros this issue with as little code as possible?

Comment: @Sampson Thanks.  I will try and put something together this weekend.

Comment: @Sampson are you still working on Edge? I have similar issue and maybe I could provide you a code sample?